# ng build --aot interprets :host pseudo class selector incorrectly

Tags: css, angular, less, angular2-aot, ng-build

I have using pseudo class selector in my .less css file to change the background color when a product is selected.

```
:host(.selected .message) {
  background: blue;
}
```

It works fine with ng build JIT, but doesn't work for AOT.
When I inspect the Elements in chrome, 
for JIT build:

```
.selected[_nghost-c16]  .message[_ngcontent-c16]{
   background: #8f5f0
}
```

for AOT build:

```
.selected.message[_nghost-c16]{
   background: #8f5f0
}
```

AOT interprets :host incorrectly. what did i do wrong?